# Magento 2: Admin grid creation

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, grid, magento2-dev-beta

What difference between magento 2-dev-beta grid creation and Magento 2 release. When i update magento to release version i saw this: [image]

Can someone explain to me what i need to delete or add?

**UPDATE:**

di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Webinse\Crm\Api\Data\RemindersInterface" type="Webinse\Crm\Model\Reminders"/>
<virtualType name="CrmGirdFilterPool" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FilterPool">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="appliers" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="regular"
                  xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\RegularFilter
            </item>
            <item name="fulltext"
                  xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FulltextFilter
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
<virtualType name="RemindersGridDataProvider"
             type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collection" xsi:type="object"
                  shared="false">Webinse\Crm\Model\Resource\Reminders\Collection
        </argument>
        <argument name="filterPool" xsi:type="object" shared="false">CrmGirdFilterPool</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
</config>
```

ui_component/crm_reminders_listing.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">crm_reminders_listing.crm_reminders_listing_data_source</item>
        <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">crm_reminders_listing.crm_reminders_listing_data_source</item>
    </item>
    <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">crm_reminders_columns</item>

</argument>
<dataSource name="crm_reminders_listing_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">RemindersGridDataProvider</argument>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">crm_reminders_listing_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">reminder_id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</dataSource>
<container name="listing_top">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
    </item>
</argument>
<paging name="listing_paging">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">crm_reminders_listing.crm_reminders_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
            </item>
            <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">crm_reminders_listing.crm_reminders_listing.crm_reminders_columns.ids</item>
            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">bottom</item>
            <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="20" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="value" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">20</item>
                </item>
                <item name="30" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="value" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">30</item>
                </item>
                <item name="50" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="value" xsi:type="number">50</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">50</item>
                </item>
                <item name="100" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="value" xsi:type="number">100</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">100</item>
                </item>
                <item name="200" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="value" xsi:type="number">200</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">200</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</paging>
</container>

<columns name="crm_reminders_columns">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">crm_reminders_listing.crm_reminders_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current</item>
            </item>
            <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">crm_reminders_listing.crm_reminders_listing.crm_reminders_columns.actions</item>
                    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">applyAction</item>
                    <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">edit</item>
                        <item name="1" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="controlVisibility" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">crm_reminders_listing.crm_reminders_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="root" xsi:type="string">columns.${ $.index }</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.${ $.storageConfig.root}</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <column name="reminder_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
            </item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="full_name" class="Webinse\Crm\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Reminders">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
            </item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Reminder assign to</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="group_name">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
            </item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Reminder assign to</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="datetime">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
            </item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Start Date</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="duedatetime">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
            </item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Due Date</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="title">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
            </item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Note</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="customer_name">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
            </item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer Name</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="email">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
            </item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer Email</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="status">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
            </item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="order_increment_id" class="Webinse\Crm\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Links">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">actions</item>
                <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Reminder for Order, ID</item>
                <item name="data_type" xsi:type="string">actions</item>
                <item name="filterable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="customer_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
            </item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">actions</item>
                <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Reminder for Customer, ID</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="actions" class="Webinse\Crm\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\RemindersActions">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="draggable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">actions</item>
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">reminder_id</item>
                <item name="blockVisibility" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Action</item>
                <item name="data_type" xsi:type="string">actions</item>
                <item name="filterable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
</columns>
</listing>
```

**UPDATE 2:**

add layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<update handle="styles"/>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <uiComponent name="crm_reminders_listing"/>
        <block class="Webinse\Crm\Block\Adminhtml\Reminders" name="reminders_list"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

Comment: You can show `di.xml` file and a xml file in `view/adminhtml/ui_component` folder

Comment: @Bill Added to question.

Comment: I forgot tell you need upload your layout about `ui_component`

Comment: @Bill Check it please

Comment: Really, it very complex and longer if i explain for you. Because in new version, Magento 2 change very much about UI, `di.xml`, `ResourceModel`.

Answer (score 0):

in first look :
in mag rc Resource folder is converting to ResourceModel
you need update because i see Webinse\Crm\Model\Resource\Reminders\Collection 
change to Webinse\Crm\Model\ResourceModel\Reminders\Collection

Comment: Create grid in m2 have 2 ways. One is oldschool way like m1. And another use ui_component. My question is how to use event or dispatch if use ui_components. Can we pass it through ui ways